# Javascript - Calculating Sum of Checkboxes From Array

Tags: javascript, php

Based on the answers below I have edited the post to give some more details. Thanks everyone.

EDITED:

This is the code I have:

```
@foreach($amount_data as $amount)                          
<div class="col-sm-12">                             
<div class="input-checkbox">                               
<div class="inner"></div>
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="{{$amount->amount}}" onchange="checkTotal()" />
</div>
<span>{{$amount->item_name}} - <b>{{$amount->amount}} {{$form->currency}}</b></span>
 </div>
 @endforeach
 <br/>  Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0" />
 @endif
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkTotal() {
var sum = 0,
frm = document.getElementById("payment-form"),
cbs = frm["items[]"],
i;
for (i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
if (cbs[i].checked) {
sum += parseInt(cbs[i].value);
}
}
frm.total.value = sum;
}

</script>
```

Form info:

```
 <form action="{{url('secure-checkout/'.$form->unique_url_code)}}" method="POST" id="payment-form" name="payment-form">
```

Doesn't seem to work. No errors in console. Anything wrong?

Comment: No using jQuery? Just making sure.

Comment: This is the only code I found online that works on its own. However I could integrate it into my form. I am loading jQuery into my page as well for other purposes.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use bracket notation because of the [] in the name

```
document.listForm["items[]"][i].checked
```

```js
function checkTotal() {
  var sum = 0,
    frm = document.getElementById("payment-form"),
    cbs = frm["items[]"],
    i;
  for (i = 0; i < cbs.length; i++) {
    if (cbs[i].checked) {
      sum += parseInt(cbs[i].value);
    }
  }
  frm.total.value = sum;
}
```

```html
<form name="payment-form" id="payment-form">
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="2" onchange="checkTotal()" />2<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="5" onchange="checkTotal()" />5<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="10" onchange="checkTotal()" />10<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="items[]" value="20" onchange="checkTotal()" />20<br/> 
  Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Just tried this. This is my form. So I replaced listForm with payment-form and I am getting the error. Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment    

    <form action="{{url('secure-checkout/'.$form->unique_url_code)}}" method="POST" id="payment-form" name="payment-form">

Comment: because it thinks you are trying to subtract the two items. `payment-form`, you would also need to use bracket notation... I will fix the answer with your id.

Comment: I just edited my OP. Doesnt seem to work. I know something minor. No errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Sum of checked checkboxes array by simply using [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
function checkTotal() {
  document.listForm.total.value = Array.prototype.reduce.call(
    document.listForm.choice, 
    function (sum, el) {
      return el.checked ? sum + +el.value : sum;
    }, 0
  );
}
```

```html
<form name="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2" onchange="checkTotal()"/>2<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="5" onchange="checkTotal()"/>5<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10" onchange="checkTotal()"/>10<br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="20" onchange="checkTotal()"/>20<br/>
  Total: <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0"/>
</form>
```

Comment: does not really answer OPs problem.

Comment: @epascarello Improving the way to solve a problem is also an answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer using jQuery. Hope this helps a bit! I've separated the listener and the function as I believe it makes things easier to edit later on. You could combine them to shorten the code.

```js
//Listener for the checkbox
$("input[name='choice']").change(function() {
  sumUp();
});


//Funtion that adds the total up
function sumUp() {
  var sum = 0;

  $(" input[name='choice']:checked").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });

  $("input[name=total]").val(sum);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="listForm">
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="2" />2
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="5" />5
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="10" />10
  <br/>
  <input type="checkbox" name="choice" value="20" />20
  <br/> Total:
  <input type="text" size="2" name="total" value="0" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry. How do you know which Checkboxes to Sum. I dont see the name of checkboxes in your code. Also my checkboxes are in array. items[]

Comment: What this code does is get the value of all checked checkboxes and add them up. It is run every time a box is checked/unchecked. Looks like other answers use `Arrays` so take a look at those! I gave you a solution that doesn't. This is client side scripting, so if you want the sum on the server (for database etc) you will need to pass to the PHP using `ajax` or submit as a form, and calculate on the server.

Comment: You should actually select the checkboxes to sum, not all the checkboxes on the page.

Comment: @epascarello I know. I figured `Max I` would be able to modify the code to fit their needs precisely. I have changed my answer however to select based on the name of the checkbox, rather than the type.